# Execute multiple select queries in MySQL - SQLyog

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I am trying to execute two select queries like this in SQLyog

```
SELECT * FROM `admin`
SELECT * FROM `student`
```

I got this error
[image]

Then I tried adding semicolumn (;) at the end of first query

```
  SELECT * FROM `admin`;
  SELECT * FROM `student`
```

I am getting result of only second table

Then I tried this

```
  SELECT * FROM `admin`;
  SELECT * FROM `student`;
```

I got this error
[image]

Where m i missing?

Comment: I want result from both tables

Comment: [This link might be helpful for you](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/10897_1558731_2/Introducing-SQLyog-a-MySQL-Front-End.htm)

Comment: @LearningMode : Why `join`? OP needs to get separate result set for each query.

Comment: There are three methods of executing queries in SQLyog -- `Execute Current Query (F5)`, `Execute All Query(s) (Shift+F5)` and `Execute Selected Query (Ctrl+F5)`. If you have written multiple queries and want to execute a particular query, then place your cursor in the respective query and press `F5`.

Comment: @Ullas this solution is not working. 'F5' is just refreshing object browser. Queries are executed using F9

Comment: @mr.supercool : select both the queries and execute using `Ctrl + F5`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select(Ctrl+a) SQL query and try to execute..
There will be multiple Result tab for each result set as shown in image..,
[image].

Comment: @thanks it is working. I have selected all then click "F9" normally to execute query and it gives me the results with different tab for each query for all the queries.